# Translate the description of the app in App Store

Tags: xcode, app-store

I am translating my app via NSLocalizedString. But how do I translate the description in the App Store?

Is an operation to do in iTunes Connect or under development?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do it in iTunes connect. If I remember correctly, you must select any language that the app is in and then it will allow you to write each discription individually. Hope this helps.